# PuLP: TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects

Tags: python-3.x, pulp

I have a constraint in a linear program as follows:

```
A_i >= j * x_ijk for all i, j, k
```

where `x_ijk` are binary variables and `A_i` are given.

So I write it in PuLP as follows:

```
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            model += A[i] >= j * x[i, j, k]
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects
```

but I don't know how to fix this?

NB. I am using PuLP in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by writing the constraints as follows:

```
for i in range(I): 
    for j in range(J): 
        for k in range(K): 
            model += x[i, j, k] <= A[i]/j
```

Comment: is the problem here that you can't have decision variables in the right hand side? i had the same error and moved my decision variable and it work. i'm hoping to confirm this theory.